# Thunderbird: Automatically add calendar entry from incoming email?

Tags: email, thunderbird, calendar, lightning

In Outlook and Gmail it is customary that an incoming calendar invite will be put on the calendar automatically (in an unconfirmed state).

Is there any way to get Thunderbird to do this as well? Currently, Thunderbird will only add an event to the calendar if I accept the invite or mark it as tentative.

(I am aware this could become an issue with "calendar spam", but I haven't seen this much)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have the opposite issue: TBird places all my meeting notices silently into my Google calendar, then deletes the meeting notice. Unless I see it in my calendar I don't know.

Sometimes the notice gets left in my inbox.

This sounds bug-like to me...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1116194)